# Should I use SPUtility.ResolvePrincipal() or SPUtility.ResolveWindowsPrincipal()?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

Which of these should I use? When is it appropriate to use SPUtility.ResolvePrincipal() ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms458648%28v=office.14%29.aspx)) instead of `SPUtility.ResolveWindowsPrincipal()` ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.utilities.sputility.resolvewindowsprincipal%28v=office.14%29.aspx))? (The MSDN Documentation is not helpful in the least).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the source code through reflector it seems like

SPUtility.ResolveWindowsPrincipal only tries to resolve Windows user accounts or Groups.

SPUtility.ResolvePrincipal tries to resolve both: Windows User accounts and group as well as Sharepoint Users and Groups.